# Ajax filtering and load more with sticky ACF posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a list of posts that I am filtering with ajax with a load more button. These posts also have an ACF relationship field at the top which emulates sticky posts.

Filtering works without an issue and I did have the load more posts working until I had to integrate sticky posts.

On initial load, I have the sticky posts showing at the top, and the rest of the posts showing below. My issue is when I select load more, my sticky posts are repeating below, this also throws off my pagination for loading more.

Also, when I select the "all" option in the filters, the posts don't reset to how they were initially loaded.

Template code:

```
//Filters here

<?php $ids = get_field('sticky_projects', false, false);
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_projects',
        'post__in'          => $ids,

    ));

    $query2 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_projects',
        'post__not_in' => $ids,
        'paged' => $paged,

    ));?>

    <div class="l-container l-results" id="js-filter" data-page="1">

        <?php
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                project::render();
            endwhile;
        endif;  ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php
        if ($query2->have_posts()) :
            while ($query2->have_posts()) : $query2->the_post();
                project::render();
            endwhile;
        endif;  ?>

        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" name="number_pages" value="' . $query->max_num_pages . '" id="project_number_pages" />'; ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="flex u-align_center">
        <a class="load-more">Load more</a>
    </div>
```

Ajax call

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_project', 'filter_project');
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_project', 'filter_project');

function filter_project()
{

    // echo '<pre>';
    // print_r($_POST);
    // die();

    $projects_category = $_POST['projects_category'];
    $ids = get_field('sticky_projects', false, false);
    $meta_query = [];
    $paged = (int) $_POST['paged'];


    if (isset($projects_category) && $projects_category != 'all') {
        $meta_query[] = [
            'key' => 'projects_category',
            'value' => $projects_category,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ];

        $meta_query['relation'] = 'LIKE';


        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'cpt_projects',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => $meta_query,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'paged' => $paged,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($args);
        // die();

        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                project::render();
            endwhile;
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="number_pages" value="' . $query->max_num_pages . '" id="project_number_pages" />';

        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else if ($projects_category = 'all') {

        $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'cpt_projects',
            'post__in'          => $ids,

        ));

        $query2 = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'cpt_projects',
            'post__not_in' => $ids,
            'paged' => $paged,

        ));

        // echo '<pre>';
        // print_r($args);
        // die();


        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            project::render();
        endwhile;

        // wp_reset_postdata();


        while ($query2->have_posts()) : $query2->the_post();
            project::render();
        endwhile;
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="number_pages" value="' . $query->max_num_pages . '" id="project_number_pages" />';

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    die();
}
```

Script

```
  $('#filter-form').on('click', 'input', function (e) {

      $(this).parents('li').siblings().removeClass('active')
      $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active');

      filter_form();

    });

    //Separate event for clicking on the 'load-more' button (which should be added to the form with the class "load-more"
    $('body').on('click', 'a.load-more', function (e) {
      filter_form(true);

    });

    function filter_form(next_page = false) {

      var page = $('#js-filter').data('page'); //get the current page
      var totalpages = $('#project_number_pages').val(); //get the current page

      if (next_page) {
        page += 1;
      } else {
        page = 1;
      }
      $('#js-filter').data('page', page); //save back to the data attribute

      console.log('Page is ' + page + ' total pages is ' + totalpages);
      if (page >= totalpages) {
        $('a.load-more').hide();
      } else {
        $('a.load-more').show();
      }


      var projects_category = $('input[name="projects_category"]:checked').val();
      var ajax_data = {
        projects_category: projects_category,
        action: 'filter_project',
        nonce: winc.nonce,
        posts_per_page: 4,
        paged: page

      };

      $.ajax({
        url: winc.ajaxurl,
        data: ajax_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (response) {
          if (next_page) {
            $('#js-filter').append(response);
          } else {
            $('#js-filter').html(response);
          }
        },

        error: function (response) {
          console.warn(response);

        },
      });
    }


  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: _"My issue is when I select load more, my sticky posts are repeating below"_ - so - don't select/output those then, when you are on any different page than page 1?

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks CBroe, I've updated my ajax call to just get posts that aren't in the ACF field. But now when I select all in the filter, it isn't looping through the acf fields first and keeping those posts at the top and returning to as it appeared on the first load.

Comment: Can't tell where you are actually creating your filters, resp. what data you are passing to the backend based on those. But it would probably make sense to automatically reset the page number to 1, when the user changes any of your filtering criteria ... (Going from "page 137 showing results for category Shoes" to "page 137 showing results for category T-Shirts" can hardly make sense to begin with?)